# Angular2 - Google indexing loader instead of redirected home page

Tags: seo, googlebot, angular.js

I'm working on a multilanguage app in Angular. Universal is already setup and working but I have issue with googlebot indexing the page.

When user navigates to url `https://example.com` only loader from index.html is presented and app will redirect to proper country/language page after figuring out users preferences. so for example user will land on `https://example/com/gb/en`.

Because of this redirection we have a problem with Google as its cashing this loader screen instead of redirected page with proper content.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: This could be a situation where you should implement the x-default hreflang tag:https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html

Comment: @Max thank you for response. Does that apply if my main page isn't the default one? It is purely used for redirecting user to correct localized page so its presenting only loader and Google is indexing this loader only.

Comment: did you use navigat() to do the re routing?